# How to consolidate data from different geolocation database Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-sync

Recently I create a webapp on azure environment. It is a simple SPA that use a Database in the same geolocation. I have a plan to delivery the same SPA in another geolocation.

But on top these webapp I would like to build another SPA to be able to monitoring and check how is going the usage of my webapp. Like in the geolocation 1 I have a table of clientes with 5 clients, in the geolocation 2 I have the same table with only clients of that region. In this manage application I will be able to see all clientes.

At this point I'm not sure if I should have a geolocation replication and have all data from all clients in all Databases or if I can make a master Database that will receive the information from others geolocation.

My question is: What is the best approach to consolidate the information that could be accessible from my Manage App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use Azure SQL Data Sync. You can create a central database (it will be considered a hub database) that will receive data from other databases (member databases). Azure SQL Data Sync can handle bi-directional synchronization but you only need synchronization to work from members databases to the hub. At the end you can create consolidated reports from your customers using your hub database as data source. To get started with Azure SQL Data Sync please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).